# Changes in TFP and wage rates across firms

Tags: labor-economics, general-equilibrium

Assume that you have two firms, firm A and firm B. Firm A faces the
production function:
$$
Y_{A}=A_{A}F\left(K_{A},L_{A}\right)
$$
and firm B faces:
$$
Y_{B}=A_{B}F\left(K_{B},L_{B}\right)
$$
Factors are paid their marginal products. In other words:
$$
w=MP_{L}
$$
for both A and B, such that:
$$
w=A_{A}F_{L_{A}}\left(K_{A},L_{A}\right)=A_{B}F_{L_{B}}\left(K_{B},L_{B}\right)
$$

Factor markets clear such that the wage level $w$ solves :
$$
L_{A}^{-1}\left(w^{*},A_{A},K_{A}\right)+L_{B}^{-1}\left(w^{*},A_{B},K_{B}\right)=L^{S}
$$
where $L^{s}=L_{A}+L_{B}$

My question is this: does $A_{A}$ changing have any effect on the
equilibrium wage? If it doesn't, the comparative static becomes easy
(i.e. $L_{A}$ goes down). But, if it does, then how can we show it
in this model?

Comment: Your last two equations imply that $w=L^S$ ?

Comment: sorry I'll correct that- should be the inverse function.

Comment: This setting is too parsimonious to be a general equilibrium model. What goods do two firms produce? How agents supply labor? Do you allow a firm has 0 production? etc.

Comment: With just 1 labour market, it is a partial equilibrium, indeed. The last equation defines implicitly the equilibrium wage $w^*$ as a function of $L^S,A_A, A_B,K_A, K_B$, which should be taken into account for comparative statics.